# variables passes null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session

I have tried setting my session values, but every time I want to display the text a user has entered in the previous page it returns null

I have three pages Subscriber details, Package Selection and Bank Details, all three pages follow each other and the user has filled all pages with his/her desired info and clicks next, they are directed to a page where all the info they entered are displayed.

I cant seem too see what I'm doing wrong?

SubscriberDetails.aspx

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FullName = txtFullName.Text;
    string CompanyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
    string Vat = txtVAT.Text;
    string ContactNumber = txtContactNumber.Text;
    string Fax = txtFax.Text;
    string District = txtDistrict.Text;
    string Street = txtStreet.Text;
    string City = txtCity.Text;
    string Code = txtPostal.Text;
    string Trading = txtTrading.Text;
    string Id = txtID.Text;
    string ContactPerson = txtContactPerson.Text;
    string Email = txtEmail.Text;

        Session["FullName"] = FullName;
        Session["CompanyName"] = CompanyName;
        Session["VAT"] = Vat;
        Session["ContactNumber"] = ContactNumber;
        Session["Fax"] = Fax;
        Session["District"] = District;
        Session["City"] = City;
        Session["Street"] = Street;
        Session["Code"] = Code;
        Session["Trading"] = Trading;
        Session["ID"] = txtID.Text;
        Session["ContactPerson"] = ContactPerson;
        Session["Email"] = Email;

}
```

Final.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Fullname"]))
    {
        lblFullName.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblFullName.Text = Session["FullName"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["CompanyName"]))
    {
        lblCompanyName.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblCompanyName.Text = Session["CompanyName"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["VAT"]))
    {
        lblVat.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblVat.Text = Session["VAT"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["ContactNumber"]))
    {
        lblContactNumber.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblContactNumber.Text = Session["ContactNumber"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Fax"]))
    {
        lblFax.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblFax.Text = Session["Fax"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["District"]))
    {
        lblDistrict.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblDistrict.Text = Session["District"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Street"]))
    {
        lblStreet.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblStreet.Text = Session["Street"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["City"]))
    {
        lblCity.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        lblCity.Text = Session["City"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Code"]))
    {
        lblCode.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblCode.Text = Session["Code"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Trading"]))
    {
        lblTrading.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblTrading.Text = Session["Trading"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["ID"]))
    {
        lblID.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblID.Text = Session["ID"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["ContactPerson"]))
    {
        lblContactPerson.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblContactPerson.Text = Session["ContactPerson"].ToString();
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["Email"]))
    {
        lblMail.Text = "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
    lblMail.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `string FullName = txtFullName.Text;` returning null, or is `Session["Fullname"]` returning null?

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps look into the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx). This would simplify your code and you could have something like `lblContactPerson.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["ContactPerson"]) ? "N/A" : Session["ContactPerson"].ToString();` so that you don't have pages of if statements.

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't have many options there, if that is happening you have an issue with your session. Perhaps every other request is initiating a new session, check that to make sure it is not happening.

Check with:

```
Session.SessionID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one piece of code using `TextBox` controls and the lower using `Label` controls.

You aren't, maybe, reading the wrong ones, are you?

This as just an FYI: We get customer complaints on our websites if we fill in values like "N/A". Most people seem to prefer to see the blank spaces, which would also simplify your code:

```
lblVariable.Text = string.Format("{0}", Session["Variable"]);
```

Variable, obviously, needs to change with your Session and Control variable names.